# Center image above UIButton title

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am have custom UIButton that is 1/4 in height/width of the view. What I am trying to do is set an image above the button's title with both of them being centered in said button.

Code:

```
CGRect imageFrame= CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80);
UIEdgeInsets imageInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 30, 0);
UIEdgeInsets titleInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(80, 0, 0, 0);

btnSideSettings = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnSideSettings.frame = settingsFrame;
[btnSideSettings setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnSideSettings"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnSideSettings.imageView.frame = imageFrame;
btnSideSettings.imageEdgeInsets = imageInset;
btnSideSettings.titleEdgeInsets = titleInset;
btnSideSettings.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[btnSideSettings setTitle:@"Settings" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Result:
[image]

I've tried a few variants of the above code, mostly editing the insets. If I comment out adding the picture, the title will center just fine as well. Appreciate any help.

Comment: btnSideSettings.frame = settingsFrame; ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to manipulate the image and text on the button you can add your own subviews (an image view and a label) and then you have complete and explicit control over the size and position of the elements.

Comment: Ended up doing this, much easier to maintain.